# Weak convergence result in Levy's Continuity Theorem

Tags: probability-theory, continuity, weak-convergence, probability-limit-theorems

I quote a part of *Levy's Continuity Theorem* and its proof.

> **Theorem**
>    Let $\left(\mu_n\right)_{n\geq1}$ be a sequence of probability measures on $\mathbb{R}^d$, and let
>    $\left(\hat{\mu}_n\right)_{n\geq1}$ denote their Fourier transforms (aka characteristic functions). If 
>    $\mu_n$ converges weakly (that is, *in distribution*) to a probability measure $\mu$, then 
>    $\hat{\mu}_n(u)\rightarrow\hat{\mu}(u)$ for all $u\in\mathbb{R}^d.$
>
> **Proof**
>     Suppose $\mu_n$ converges weakly to $\mu$. Since $e^{iux}$ is continuous and bounded in modulus,
>     $$\hat{\mu}_n(u)={\displaystyle \int e^{iux}\mu_n(dx)}$$
>     converges to 
>     $$\hat{\mu}(u)={\displaystyle \int e^{iux}\mu(dx)}$$

My **question** is:
which is the result implicitly used so as to state that:

"Since $f=e^{iux}$ is continous and bounded in modulus
$$\mu_n\xrightarrow{\mathcal{D}}\mu\Rightarrow\hat{\mu}_n(u)={\displaystyle \int e^{iux}\mu_n(dx)}\to\hat{\mu}(u)={\displaystyle \int e^{iux}\mu(dx)}\hspace{0.5cm}\text{"}\,?$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Portmanteau theorem says, among other things, that
$$\mu_n \to \mu \mathrm{\ weakly}$$
iff
$$\forall f \in C_b: \int fd \mu_n \to \int fd \mu$$

What you are asking for uses this with your particular choice for $f$.

Comment: Thank you a lot. Could you please give me a reference as to the result you have mentioned in your answer?

Comment: Sure, check the book "Real analysis and probability" by Dudley, section 11.1 p 385 for a treatment of this result where the domain is a Polish space (separable completely metrizable space).

Answer (score 1):

The result is an application of the [Portmanteau Theorem](http://theanalysisofdata.com/probability/8_5.html).

Comment: So, by Portmanteau *NOT ONLY* $\mu_n\xrightarrow{\mathcal{D}}\mu\Rightarrow\hat{\mu}_n(u)={\displaystyle \int e^{iux}\mu_n(dx)}\to\hat{\mu}(u)={\displaystyle \int e^{iux}\mu(dx)}$ *BUT ALSO* $\hat{\mu}_n(u)={\displaystyle \int e^{iux}\mu_n(dx)}\to\hat{\mu}(u)={\displaystyle \int e^{iux}\mu(dx)}\Rightarrow\mu_n\xrightarrow{\mathcal{D}}\mu$? Henceforth, are they equivalent? However, a doubt still remains, since here we start from convergence of probability measures and end up with convergence of a function of $x$, not of a function of the probability measures @YashaswiMohanty